# Python urllib2 > HTTP Proxy > HTTPS request

Tags: python, proxy, https, urllib2

This work fine:

```
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener(
                urllib2.HTTPHandler(),
                urllib2.HTTPSHandler(),
                urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://user:pass@proxy:3128'}))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
print urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()
```

But, if **http** change to **https**:

```
...
print urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com').read()
```

There are errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Temp\6\tmp.py", line 13, in <module>
    print urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com').read()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 124, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 389, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 407, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 367, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 1154, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 1121, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060]
```

Why and how solve this problem?

Comment: if you are reading this: please mark the correct answer as correct. This is to ensure that nobody wastes their time trying to answer an already answered question. It is also a nice way of saying thanks to the person who came up with a solution for your problem

Answer (score 17):

Change this line:

```
urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://user:pass@proxy:3128'}))
```

to this:

```
urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': 'http://user:pass@proxy:3128'}))
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': 'https://user:pass@proxy:3128'}))

Change the second http to https if you want to use both http and an http proxy in your urllib2

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, errno 10060 is a winsock error meaning the connection timed out.  Are you able to reach https://www.google.com from the same machine using a web browser with a proxy set to http://user:pass@proxy:3128 ?  Are you sure your proxy server can handle both https and http on the same port?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#id15) for urllib2 says the following:

> Note: Currently urllib2 does not support fetching of https locations
>   through a proxy. However, this can be enabled by extending urllib2 as
>   shown in [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/456195/).

I must admit above recipe didn't work right away for Jython 2.5.3, but I'm still trying.

**UPDATE**: I applied [this patch](http://bugs.python.org/issue1424152) to Jython 2.5.3, and it worked for me. I can fetch HTTPS resources over a proxy server now.

**UPDATE2**: Here is the code to query HTTPS resources with Basic authentication over HTTP Proxy (DON'T FORGET TO INSTALL PATCH FIRST (see previous update)):

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.transport.https import HttpAuthenticated

credentials = dict(username='...', password='...', proxy={'https': 'host:port', 'http': 'host:port'})
t = HttpAuthenticated(**credentials)
url = 'https://example.com/service?wsdl'
client = Client(url, transport=t)
print client.service.getFoo()
```