# Python - How to handle HTTPS request with (Urllib2 + SSL) though a HTTP proxy

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy

I am trying to test a proxy connection by using urllib2.ProxyHandler. However, there probably some situation that I am going to request a HTTPS website (eg: https://www.whatismyip.com/)

Urllib2.urlopen() will throw ERROR if request a HTTPS site. So I tried to use a helper function to rewrite the URLOPEN method.

Here is the helper function:

```
def urlopen(url, timeout):
    if hasattr(ssl, 'SSLContext'):
        SslContext = ssl.create_default_context()
        SslContext.check_hostname = False
        SslContext.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        return urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout, context=SslContext)
    else:
        return urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)
```

This helper function based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268548/python-ignore-certicate-validation-urllib2)

Then I use:

```
urllib2.install_opener(
     urllib2.build_opener(
         urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1:8080'})
     )
)
```

to setup http proxy for urllib.opener.

Ideally, it should working when i request a website by using `urlopen('http://whatismyip.com', 30)` and it should pass all traffic through http proxy.

However, the `urlopen()` will fall into `if hasattr(ssl, 'SSLContext')` all the time even if it is a HTTP site. In addition, HTTPS site is not using HTTP proxy either. This cause the HTTP proxy become invalid and all traffic going through unproxied network

I also tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248895/4196468) to change HTTP into HTTPS `urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': '127.0.0.1:8080'})` but it still not working.

My proxy is working. If i am using `urllib2.urlopen()` instead of the rewrite version `urlopen()`, it works for HTTP site.

But, I do need consider the suitation if the `urlopen` gonna need to be used on a HTTPS ONLY site.

How to do that?

Thanks

**UPDATE1:** I cannot get this work with Python 2.7.11 and some of server working properly with Python 2.7.5. I assue it is python version issue.

Urllib2 will not go through HTTPS Proxy so all HTTPS web address will failed to use proxy.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you pass `context` argument to `urllib2.urlopen()` then urllib2 creates opener [itself](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a06454b1afa1/Lib/urllib2.py#l147) instead of [using](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a06454b1afa1/Lib/urllib2.py#l153) the global one, which is the one that gets set when you call `urllib2.install_opener()`. As a result your instance of `ProxyHandler` which you meant to be used is not being used.
The solution is not to install opener but to use the opener directly. When building your opener, you have to pass both an instance of your `ProxyHandler` class (to set proxies for http and https protocols) and an instance of `HTTPSHandler` class ([to set https context](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a06454b1afa1/Lib/urllib2.py#l1235)).

I created https://bugs.python.org/issue29379 for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would suggest the use of something such as `python-requests` as it will alleviate a lot of the issues with setting up the proxy using `urllib2` directly. When using `requests` with a proxy you will have to do: (From their [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/?highlight=proxy#proxies))

```
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
}

requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

And disabling SSL Certificate verification is as simple as passing `verify=False` the `requests.get` command above. However, this should be used sparingly and the actual issue with the SSL Cert verification should be resolve.

Comment: I tried that, but requests.get will only return Status Code and i need certain content from the website (e.g the ip address)

Comment: @SharkIng You should be able to retrieve the content through: `var = request.get(...);
print var.content`.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution is to pass `context` into `HTTPSHandler` and pass this handler into `build_opener` together with `ProxyHandler`:

```
proxies = {'https': 'http://localhost:8080'}
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxies)
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
handler = urllib2.HTTPSHandler(context=context)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy, handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

Now you can view all your HTTPS requests/responses in your proxy.